# Lost power because of an overheat

Tags: shutdown

I have a redmi note 3 pro that has lost power after an overheat from a hot day in the car. I'd like to take part in reviving it back from the dead (if it's possible) because it was a great phone. I know how to open a phone and replace parts but don't know which parts to replace... I've bought a ribbon cable connecting the charging circuit with the motherboard, together with a new battery and a charging circuit. I've replaced them and it powered on, though it isn't charging. I'd like to know if there is something I missed in order to complete the "revival". If anyone has any suggestions for a better title and some more tags, they are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are lucky the battery is just dead. Does it power on when you try to charge it? For the battery have you tried to search on Youtube for `redmi note 3 battery replace`?

Comment: @Robert it does power on but it's not charging, so either there is something wrong with the motherboard or the charging circuit.